# Embedding Cgi video in site

Tags: c#, javascript, cgi

Hello All I have various web cameras i would like to embed in my site

```
http://81.137.212.183:4483/GetData.cgi
```

The problem is at times the cameras go down so i need to check they are active in c# before attempting to render:

```
<img height="240" width="320" src="http://81.137.212.183:4483/GetData.cgi" />
```

Please can someone advise how i can check the cgi is active in c# or any other recommendation. If i simple load the cgi and it is down it causes the browser to crash

One recommendation was to use the code below:

The problem with the below approach is the site is forever loading and a fav icon is never shown as can be seen http://www.camsecure.co.uk/

newImage = new Image();

```
function LoadNewImage() {
    var unique = new Date();
    document.images.webcam.src = newImage.src;
    newImage.src = "http://collectart.dyndns.org:4484/Jpeg/CamImg.jpg?time=" + unique.getTime();
}

function InitialImage() {

    var unique = new Date();
    newImage.onload = LoadNewImage();
    newImage.src = "http://collectart.dyndns.org:4484/Jpeg/CamImg.jpg?time=" + unique.getTime();
    document.images.webcam.src = "http://collectart.dyndns.org:4484/Jpeg/CamImg.jpg?time=" + unique.getTime();

    document.images.webcam.onload = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you need to put some security over that first link. It appears the camera settings are public and available to anyone.

If the only problem is the long loading times slowing the rest of the site down, you could load the images in an `iframe` rather than directly in an image tag -- then the hang is only in the iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://81.137.212.183:4483/Simple/home.htm?IMG"></iframe>
```

To check the IP camera is up, you could simply try to get it's host page:

```
using System.Net.Http;
...

var uri = new Uri("http://81.137.212.183:4483/Simple/index.htm");
var task = new HttpClient().GetAsync(uri);
if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) && task.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // SUCCESS!
}
else
{
    // FAILURE... try next camera
}
```

However, it looks like the image .cgi location can still fail if the camera is available. In that case it would be best to load in an iframe even if you get success.

Comment: the main problem is checking if the camera is up and running before trying to load the GetData.cgi. How could i check this?

Comment: how can the image cgi still fail if the camera is available? Sorry for so many questions. Presume embedding the cgi is better than the javascript way? What do i need to do around security measures, any urls you can recommend. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Probably shortcomings in the camera software, or quality settings that don't work so well. You should go to the 'Users' tab add one with a password, then set to 'Authorization' to 'Needed'